# Why certain recursive types fail to compile

Tags: scala, types

I run into typecheck error that I could not understand. Two pieces of code are alike, but only one compiles. The compiler gives totally useless error message:

> error: type arguments [I] do not conform to type DY's type parameter bounds [I <: Sample.this.Y]

The code in question:

```
trait Sample {
  type X
  type DX[I <: X] <: X
  type Y = Aux[X]
  type DY[I <: Y] <: Y
  type Z = Bux[X]
  type DZ[I <: Z] <: Z
  type DW[I <: Z#C] <: Z#C
}
type Aux[I] = Sample { type X = I }

trait Dep {
  type B
  type C = Aux[B]
}
type Bux[A] = Dep { type B = A }

type UseX[I <: S#X, S <: Sample] = S#DX[I] // ok
type UseY[I <: S#Y, S <: Sample] = S#DY[I] // fails
type UseZ[I <: S#Z, S <: Sample] = S#DZ[I] // ok
type UseW[I <: S#Z#C, S <: Sample] = S#DW[I] // fails
```

Why I could not reference the type itself?

---

#### Update

I remain confused as much as was when I wrote the question. But I still managed to trick compiler into doing his work. And that only heightened my confusion.

The problem is same type arguments are accepted or rejected based on type bound. If type bound is the same as argument (introducing recursion therefore) it is rejected. But if I wrap recursion in a type it is accepted normally. So all I need is to relay recursion call

```
trait Sample {
  type X
  type Y = Aux[X]
  type Z = Bux[X]
  type DY[I <: Y] <: Y
  type DD[I <: Z] = DY[I#C]
}

type UseY[I <: S#Y, S <: Sample] = S#DY[I] // still fails
type UseD[I <: S#Z, S <: Sample] = S#DD[I] // miraculously works
```

But it requires to wrap every type level call in the `Bux` wrapper type.

Comment: Adding the compilation error would help

Comment: I put the error before the code.

Comment: it's have a cycle,designed to be?

Comment: Yes. I get an error implementing sort of type list which is essentially recursive structure. After that I reduced code to a minimal reproducible example. Note that using `Z` is still ok even though it contains recursion but does not call it explicitly.

Comment: this compiles: 

`type UseY[I <: S#Y, S <: Aux[I]] = S#DY[I]`
`type UseW[I <: S#Z#C, S <: Aux[I]] = S#DW[I]`

Comment: any particular reason for this? What are you trying to accomplish? Are you simply pressing random keys until something doesn't compile and then wonder? :)

Comment: I'm trying to write smart `TList` - type level list of types with extra operations and specifications

Answer (score 1):

So, `S#Y` means "*some* type `Y`, defined in *any* instance of `S`".
On the other hand, `type DY[I <: Y]` means "`I` must be a subclass of `Y` declared in *this* instance".

So, when you say `type UseY[I <: S#Y, S <: Sample] = S#DY[I]`, it fails, because `I` is constrained to be a subclass of `Y` from *some* `S`, but `DY` wants it to be a subclass of *the same* `S` where `DY` is declared.

Comment: The same logic applies for `X` and `Z` but they works, and only `Y` fails.